# How can I use a twig variable as a form field name

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a form template which has a repeated block for several similar form fields. It is used as follows:

```
{# form_template.html.twig #}
{{ include ('company-select.html.twig', {field: 'companiesInclude'})
{{ include ('company-select.html.twig', {field: 'companiesExclude'})
{{ include ('company-select.html.twig', {field: 'companiesLinked'})
```

Now I have a company select template, which looks as follows:

```
{# company-select.html.twig  (simplified, the actual template is much more complex) #}
<div class="form form-field selector" id="{{ field }}">
  {{ form_label(form.field) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.field) }}    

</div>
```

The way it is, the template fails, because 'field' is not a property of the FormView class.

How can I make the template interpolate the twig variable into the form_xxx function call as an actual field name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A property of an object or an array element in twig can either be accessed via the dot notation (`.`) or via the square bracket one (`[]`).

If your property happens to be a twig variable, you will need to use the later form.

So in your case:

- `form_label(form[field])`
- `form_widget(form[field])`

Your code in *company-select.html.twig* ending up being:

```
<div class="form form-field selector" id="{{ field }}">
  {{ form_label(form[field]) }}
  {{ form_widget(form[field]) }}  
</div>
```

This is, in a really simplified example, testable [here](https://twigfiddle.com/f8xa9t).

*Note that, in a more complex flavour, you can also use the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html)*

> `.`, `[]`: Gets an attribute of a variable.

<sup>*Source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators*</sup>
<sup>*Also worth reading on the same note: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#variables*</sup>

Comment: Changed the way 'companyInclude' is generated - now it all works fine.